# Scalaz: How to Chain Future[List[A]], Option[A] and Future[Option[A]] And Report Individual Error

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

```
(for {
  orderId <- ListT(extractParamFromHttp(request).toList) // extractParamFromHttp(request) returns Option[Long]
  order <- ListT(serviceA.retrieve(orderId).map(_.toList))  // serviceA.retrieve(...) returns Future[Option[Order]]
  items <- ListT(serviceB.retrieve(order.id).map(_.toList))  // serviceB.retrieve(...) returns Future[Seq[OrderItem]]
  } yield items).map(...) // convert items to JSON and return as Future[Result]
```

The code above works and it returns a Nil when any of them fail to get info if incorrect input is given or missing input. I want response with more specific error messages instead of empty List. for example, if the params in the HTTP request is not found. I want to tell to the sender that HTTP params are missing or the given order id is not found. Would using EitherT or Either helps? how should i go about this? thanks

**Update 1**

I solved it using Scalaz `EitherT` and `Either` (hint from `Validation`) and pasted my solution here with minor changes,

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class Order(id: Long, desc: String)
case class Vendor(id: Long, name: String)

def extractHeader(valid: Boolean): Option[String] = if (valid) Some("bob") else None
def retrieveVendor(username: String, found: Boolean): Future[Option[Vendor]] = 
  if (found) Future.successful(Some(Vendor(103, "Bob Enterprise"))) else Future.successful(None)
def retrieveOrders(vendorId: Long, found: Boolean): Future[List[Order]] =
  if (found) Future.successful(List(Order(1, "Product 1"), Order(2, "Product 2"))) else Future.successful(List.empty[Order])

def output(result: Future[\/[String, AnyRef]]) = result.foreach {
  case -\/(s) => println(s"Error: $s")
  case \/-(ys @ x :: xs) => println(ys)
  case \/-(s) => println(s)
}

def orders(valid: Boolean, userFound: Boolean, vendorFound: Boolean) = for {
  username <- EitherT(Future.successful(extractHeader(valid) \/> "Bad headers"))   // Option[String]
  vendor <- EitherT(retrieveVendor(username, userFound).map(_ \/> "Bad username")) // Future[Option[Vendor]]
  orders <- EitherT(retrieveOrders(vendor.id, vendorFound).map {                   // Future[Seq[Order]]    
    case Nil => "Bad vendor".left
    case xs => xs.right
  })                                                                              
} yield orders

output(orders(false,false, true).run)
```

Refer to the answer for non-Scalaz solution

**Update 2**

For applicative form (if required) to this solution or more elaborative solution, please refer to [here](https://gist.github.com/sshark/e7d2a8c561cc972407e96b16517f4a24)

Comment: Look at scalaz.Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you toss scalaz, it brings no value to this use case, just makes things more confusing for you. 
Failure to keep things simple is usually the reason for problems like this.

```
def ifExists[T, R](opt: Option[T], err: String)(f: T => Future[R]) = 
  opt.fold(Future.failed(new IllegalArgumentException(err))(f)

for(
   order <- ifExists(extractParamFromHttp(request), "Missing param) {
     serviceA.retrieve(_)
   }
   items <- ifExists(order, "Order not found") { serviceB.retrieve(_) }
   result <- ...
) yield result
```

This returns `Future[Result]`, that, upon completion will contain either the final result or an exception indicating the reason for failure. 
The caller can then inspect the exception with `future.handle...` or handle both successes and failures with `future.transform` or `future.onComplete`

Comment: I do agree I should not complicate matter any more than they needed to. for this case, I find the scalaz solution is concise and these are the few areas i think i can make good use of them. i might change later :)

Comment: "concise"??? It is actually _longer_ than mine ... and _does not handle all of the cases_ (thus, your question here) ...